# Novice XML Parsing

Tags: ruby, xml-parsing, rexml

I am learning XML parsing with RUBY(infact never did any XML parsing before). Plz refer this link - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_xml_xslt.htm
In the DOM-like Parsing example, it prints all Movie Title followed by Movie Type. But i want to print Title and type as a pair, and then move to next xml node.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean that you want to print `title and type as a pair`? Do you mean that you don't want `type` to be an element under `title`, but instead to have the `type` attribute at the same level of the XML heirarchy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ask the movie for any of its elements by name by using an array-like syntax:

```
# This will output all the movie titles and types                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
xmldoc.elements.each("collection/movie"){|e|
   puts "Movie Title : " + e.attributes["title"]
   puts e.elements["type"].text
}
```

Comment: Also: you may want to look at a gem called Nokogiri, which provides easier and faster XML processing and has excellent doucmentation.

Comment: Thank you so much!! works :))) will look at Nokogiri as well!